# How to create dynamic header for tables in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, logic, html-table

My array -

```
$myfinal = Array(
        13 => Array
            (
            5 => 85,
            4 => 75,
            3 => 65,
            2 => 55 
            ),
        12 => 11,
        7  => 100
        );
```

This is what I want to generate(table) dynamically -

Required Output - http://jsfiddle.net/LCKW6/

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" border="3" bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
<tbody>

    <tr bgcolor="#99cccc">
    <th colspan="4">13</th>
    <th colspan="0">12</th>
    <th colspan="0">7</th>
    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="#99cccc">
    <th width="70">5</th>
    <th width="70">4</th>
    <th width="70">3</th>
    <th width="70">2</th>
    <th width="70">No subcat</th>
    <th width="70">No subcat</th>
    </tr>

    <tr align="right">
    <td>85</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>65</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>100</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

My code try, I tried with the first tr and th but for the rest I am confused with the loop:

```
<?php
$myfinal = Array(
                13 => Array
                        (
                        5 => 85,
                        4 => 75,
                        3 => 65,
                        2 => 55 
                        ),
                12 => 11,
                7  => 100
             );

?>
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" border="3" bgcolor="#c3cece">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#99cccc">
<?php
foreach( $myfinal as $key => $value )
{
    if( is_array($value) )
    {
    echo '<th colspan="'.sizeof($value).'">'.$key.'</th>';
    }
    else 
    {
    echo '<th colspan="0">'.$key.'</th>';
    }
}

?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You need `colspan = "1"`, not 0

Comment: Do you need arbitrary depth or just 2 layers?

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse This type of output I need http://jsfiddle.net/LCKW6/

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse No actually I just need to set table headers like that way..its all going to be dynamic..as lower trs will be populated from another table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for two layers... Arbitrary layers is probably possible but much more complex.

```
// Top row
echo '<tr>';
foreach( $myfinal as $key => $value )
{
    if( is_array($value) )
    {
        echo '<th colspan="'.sizeof($value).'">'.$key.'</th>';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<th colspan="1">'.$key.'</th>';
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
//Middle row
echo '<tr>';
foreach( $myfinal as $key => $value )
{
    if( is_array($value) ) 
    { 
        foreach($value as $key => $column) {
            echo '<th colspan="1">'.$key.'</th>';
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<th colspan="1">No subcat</th>';
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
//Data
echo '<tr>';
foreach( $myfinal as $key => $value )
{
    if( is_array($value) ) 
    { 
        foreach($value as $key => $column) {
            echo '<td>'.$column.'</td>';
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    }
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Its working fine..but since I have a dynamic dataset..will the code set i am using this time ok  or it needs modification..as I think its not the appropriate way I am handling the data this time

Comment: Most people store data as `$array[$row]['column'];`. This is easy to loop and parse.

The format you are suggesting above is much different which will probably give you many problems along the way, apart from this bit.

Comment: @PhilpWhitehouse yeah I too feel so..thx a lot man :) +1 and green tick :)..sometimes I really feel lost with theloops :( just let me know if you have any idea to learn and practice :)